# Font Setting in VS2010 - missing FixedSys

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts

After installing VS2010 yesterday - (both VS2005 and VS2010 installed), I can't find the "**FixedSys**" style font from the Fonts and Colors -> Font (pull down list).

I can still use the font in VS2005.

[update]
I just searched "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts", there is no Fixedsys style in the folder.

Any suggestions on how to make FixedSys available as a choice in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @pcampbell winxp used. There is no **vgafix** avaliable as a choice in my vs2010 too. thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure, but this might be happening because Fixedsys isn't TrueType.  [Fixedsys Excelsior](http://www.fixedsysexcelsior.com/) is a TrueType font based on Fixedsys that should work instead.

Comment: @MiffTheFox, Thanks. I installed FSEX300.ttf successfully - via your link, but it still doesn't work well. (http://bylang.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pdoEuOUUky04y9aEZQFA7N3oOuiqahoT3UGSkdRa8DvKnOV9s-H64A8kV9raHBk0dwKEwkS8SefiCyoyMFCGsmMbUlYEnhk32/FontIssue.JPG)

Comment: @MiffTheFox, Oh. I found the reason. After I setting the FSEX300 size from 10 to 12. It works very well. :-)

Comment: What the hell, now Fixedsys Excelsior doesn't work in Visual Studio 2012.  It's listed as an option (as is Fixedsys), but it does nothing when you select it.  http://connectppe.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759437/cannot-set-font-fixedsys-for-the-editor

Answer (score 3):

This is because the WPF editor is supporting only TrueType fonts, and it's a

> limitation of WPF, there's no way for Visual Studio to add or reinstate support for raster fonts

See this MS Connect issue titled [Code Editor Cannot Select Fixedsys](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/538494/code-editor-cannot-select-fixedsys).